# cohomology of total space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Suppose $\mu:E\to B$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $F$. Furthermore, $F$ and $B$ have vanishing odd dimensional cohomology group. Is it true that $E$ has vanishing odd dimensional cohomology group? You can just assume $E,B,F$ are (possibly singular) algebraic variety. More specifically, you can assume the fiber $F$ is a partial flag variety. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Leray-Serre Spectral sequence is of the form $E_2^{pq}=H^p(B: H^q(F))\to H^{p+q}(E; k)$. We have that $E_2^{pq}=0$ if $p+q$ is odd, since then either $p$ or $q$ is odd. Thus the diagonal converging to $H^{n}(E; k)$ vanishes if $n$ is odd, so that the odd cohomology vanishes

Comment: Can you use the Leray-Serre spectral sequence like this if the base is not simply connected?

Comment: I believe so, since you can make sense of it in the local systems sense, but I haven't working it out explicitly, since I don't know anything about the Universal coefficent theorem for local systems.

Comment: I agree that it's likely the result holds in this setting.  I've never worked with local coefficients, so I just figured I'd ask.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your ans Kamina and your comment @Jason DeVito.  I am not too familiar with spectral sequence. Where would be a good place to learn this technique? Thank you!

Comment: Well, at least if $B$ has finite fundamental group, one can pull back the bundle along the universal covering $\tilde{B}\rightarrow B$.  The map $H^\ast(B;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^\ast(\tilde{B},\mathbb{Q})$ is injective in this case, and one can use the spectral sequence on the pulled back bundle.  @Ben:  Hatcher has a (freely available) partially complete book on spectral sequences.  I learned a lot of what I know about them from that book.

Comment: Asking where to learn spectral sequences is like asking where is the best place to be born: It is highly biased based on where one comes from. I personally suggest reading a book on algebraic topology, but one that uses heavy machinery, like Switzer. Spectral Sequences feel really inorganic if you haven't seen them. Reading Weibel's book on Homological Algebra is also superb, but only if you have a feeling for category theory and module theory.